# jquery UI dialog: load ajax data when opened first time - OOP

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, dialog

I would like to implement a jquery UI dialog that makes ajax call for data during first show action (calling ajax each time is useless). So far I can display a standard modal (just like in [jqueryui docs](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal-confirmation)). I can declare a global boolean variable that states whether data has been oaded through ajax, but having 10+ such variables is not a good architecture approach. Is it possible with js/jquery to make it more like OOP? I mean - to create an object that manages the whole dialog existence, just like in Qt, swing, etc.?

If it is possible, could anyone give me a hint on how to do that?

Comment: You could use `.data()` to attach a state variable to a DOM element (e.g. to the dialog's DOM element) to indicate whether the data is loaded.

Comment: @tcovo where should `.data` be set and where should it be retrieved?

Comment: It should be set when the state changes, and retrieved when you want to know what the state is.

Comment: Why not have the dialog be disabled and on the success function of the ajax call, re-enable it? As opposed to setting variables for after it has loaded.